# 'While' loop is running infinitely even though the condition is false

Tags: python, while-loop

There is a *while* loop in line 14. Even if I enter M or F, it still gives the input. It doesn’t continue.

```
import array

# Declaration of variables
Constnostudents = int(3)
StudentName = []
StudentGender = []

# Declaration of arrays
StudentMarkTest1 = array.array ("i", range(Constnostudents))
StudentMarktest2 = array.array ("i", range(Constnostudents))

for Counter in range(0, Constnostudents):
    StudentName.append (input("Please enter name of student"))
    StudentGender.append (input("Please enter your gender"))
    while (StudentName[Counter] !="M" or StudentName[Counter] != "F"):
        input("Please enter valid ")

    StudentMarkTest1[Counter] = int(input("Please enter marks for test 1"))
    StudentMarktest2[Counter] = int(input("Please enter marks for test 2"))

print(StudentName)
print(StudentGender)
print(StudentMarkTest1)
print(StudentMarktest2)
```

Comment: `or` should be `and`.   Otherwise entering 'M' or 'F' is True, and the while loop continues.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to check if the gender they provided is a valid one, you are giving the wrong value to the *while* loop. You need to give the "StudentGender" variable and not the "StudentName" variable. Also you are not reassigning the " StudentGender", so it doesn't matter if they are going to provide a valid answer. The loop will continue to run...

You should do:

```
while (StudentGender[Counter] !="M" and StudentGender[Counter] != "F"):
       StudentGender[Counter] = input("Please enter valid gender").upper()
```

I also added `.upper()` to the gender.

For the reason of the "and" instead of "or", look at the comments in your question.

Comment: ooh i get it. BTW changing studentname to student gender was such a noob mistake Thx

Comment: i ran it now after correcting it and it finished the infinite loop. but now it always asks me the second time; first it asks to enter gender, then i type "m", which should make the programm move on. but instead it asks me second time, and i enter "m" again, then it asks me the next question

Comment: u need to add ".upper()" to the first time u get the gender value so:

Comment: StudentGender.append (input("Please enter your gender").upper())